# How to properly remove values in dataframe that exceed a certain value (dplyr)?

Tags: r

I am converting a dataframe from counts into relative abundance using R dplyr, but for some reason I cannot get cells that end up with a relative abundance less than 0.1 to convert to a zero while keeping all other cells the same.

Sample of my dataframe:

```
Domain  Family      A13  A15    A17   A8    B15
Plants  Acanthaceae 1    0      500   500   13.666
Plants  Abrus       0    5.5    10    2.5   2
Fungi   Unknown1    0.05 0      50    0     1
```

I convert this dataframe into one that shows relative abundance for each family across all sample sites. For example the relative abundance for Acanthaceae at site A13 (which has 1 count) would be `1/1014.666 * 100`. The value would be `0.098555`. This cell would be less than `0.1`.

For any counts that end up with a relative abundance less than 0.1, I convert those to zeros. Everything else can remain. Here is my expected output where at site A13, Acanthaceae is converted to 0 and same with the unknown fungus species.

```
Domain  Family     A13  A15  A17    A8    B15
Plants  Acanthaceae 0   0    500    500   13.666
Plants  Abrus       0   5.5  10     2.5   2
Fungi   Unknown1    0   0    50     0     1
```

Here is my code that I thought would work but isn't doing what I expect:

```
# First make a mini dataframe working with just plants (repeat for each individual domain)
data <- read.csv("all_species_counts.csv", header=TRUE, stringAsFactors=FALSE)

plants <- data %>% filter(Domain == "Plants")
plants.rel <- plants[,-1:-2] %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ . * (./sum(.)*100 >= 0.1))) %>% replace(is.na(.),0)
```

But when I print plants.rel, all the values are still there and the value of 1 for Acanthaceae is not converted to a 0. It clearly has a relative abundance less than 0.1 in that whole row.

Comment: In the step, where are you converting to `NA`  You may need `replace` i.e. `replace(., . * (./sum(.)*100 >= 0.1, NA)`

Comment: I'm confused, am I inserting that separately or within the mutate command? Would it become ```mutate(where(is.numeric), replace( ~. * (./sum(.)*100>=0.1, NA))``` ?

Comment: the `~` should be `mutate(where(is.numeric), ~ replace(.,  .* (./sum(.)*100>=0.1, NA))`

Comment: Didn't work it gives an error stating ```unexpected ','``` in the whole command.

Comment: Sorry, there was a opening `(` which was not closed.  Can you close with `)`

Comment: Yea the error came up with closing the bracket.

Comment: I see that you are doing this on a subset, but should this be grouped by 'Domain' instead of filtering

Comment: Oh hang on that might be the issue. Let me play around with it...

Comment: I think that did it! Thanks so much! And in fact it should be taking relative abundance of all species in that domain in the sample. So the original code does work fine once grouping by domain.

Comment: From your expected output, I am not sure you wanted that.  You may need `rowSums`, but again some values in expected are not correct `data %>% mutate(Sum = rowSums(across(where(is.numeric)), na.rm = TRUE), across(c(where(is.numeric), - Sum),  ~.x * (.x/Sum   >= 0.1)))`

Comment: Or could be `data %>% mutate(Sum = rowSums(across(where(is.numeric)), na.rm = TRUE), across(c(where(is.numeric), - Sum),  ~.x * ((.x/Sum *100) >=  0.1)))`

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to try that but I think just splitting my data properly worked.